# Use ‘for’ or not

Tags: grammar, prepositions, writing

1. Those who missed the 20 years of the show, this is a very rare footage.
2. ‘For’ those who missed the 20 years of the show, this is a very rare footage.

Does the ‘for’ in the second sentence sound odd or not?

Comment: Source please.  Where did you get these sentences?

Comment: I don't think any native speaker would be likely to omit ***for*** in this context. And certainly from the "formal syntax" perspective, it would be completely ungrammatical to do so. Regardless of whether the adverbial clause appears before OR after the primary statement *(this is very rare footage)*, it should start with a preposition. And speaking for myself, I ***really*** don't like the article in ***a** rare footage* - to me it's on a par with ***a** software* (which I'd say always implies "non-native speaker").

Comment: "footage" is definitely uncountable, must be "this is very rare footage".

Comment: The footage is either rare or it's not.  If it's rare then it's still rare even if you've seen the last 20 years of the show.  You want to say something more like, "For those who missed the last 20 years of the show, this is footage you might never have seen before."

Answer (score 1):

No, actually. In fact, the "for" in the beginning sounds very natural, and better than missing it out.

It would make sense to skip the "for" if you're saying something like "those who missed the 20 years of the show have been sitting under a rock".

"For those" indicates something more like a disclaimer or message to the people who missed the 20 years of the show. So *for* makes more sense in this case, like: "For those who didn't watch the 20 years of the show, this is very rare footage."

Comment: The first sentence is bad, and lacks the 'for', which is **necessary**.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey what do you mean??

Comment: Sentence (1) in the OP's question does not make sense.

Comment: true. and I changed to make it make sense without a "for" although it does state a different message.